# Usage of "as long as" versus "as much time as"

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

"I will not attend the next meeting if it takes *as long as* the last meeting"

Question 1: Is it correct to use above *as long as* in the sense of *for a long time of couple of hours* ?

Question 2: If I replace *as long as* with *as much time as*, will the meaning in the context above be the same?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is fine to use *as long as* in this situation. It means *about the same amount of time as*.
2. Yes you may use *as much time as* in this situation. They are practically the same and from my opinion as a native speaker both sound natural.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also wonder if *as long as*  in this situation can signify a long period of time?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you would use that?

Comment: for example, last time the meeting took 4 hours straight (so long), I want to say if the next meeting is also going to take that long, I will not attend!